# Next.js middleware.js is very large

Tags: next.js, middleware, next.js13

I've been using next.js 13 for a while. My current version is `13.5.4`.

I noticed that even if my middleware.js file is doing nothing, it is huge in size.

```js
// middleware.js

import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(req) {
  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

This is the middleware file. ( It had lot of stuff before, I removed those to check what's happening. )

After running `npm run build`, I got this output:

```
Route (app)                              Size     First Load JS
+ First Load JS shared by all            79.4 kB
  ├ chunks/864-5a4cab91ddbf5351.js       26.6 kB
  ├ chunks/fd9d1056-d8ce21920b0c00b4.js  50.8 kB
  ├ chunks/main-app-d763ba294b8600fc.js  221 B
  └ chunks/webpack-7edd6f4b20a0468f.js   1.78 kB


ƒ Middleware                             26 kB

ℇ  (Streaming)  server-side renders with streaming (uses React 18 SSR streaming or Server Components)
λ  (Server)     server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)     automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
```

The middware.js file is **26 kB**. Why is that?